# Identity Server 4 - OpenId | Signature validation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an IdentityServer 4 application and i implemented SSO for authentication with OpenID Connect, sometimes the users are redirect to "signin-oidc" and throws the excption

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: 
>   IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: '[PII is hidden]'.

Code on client .net core:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.Name = "sintrc";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options=> {

    options.Authority = authParams.BaseUrl;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = authParams.RedirectUrl;

    options.ClientId = authParams.Client_Id;

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
    };
});
```

Comment: Isnt that error coming from the identity server?

Comment: The exception is from my client application

Comment: How have you configured the client on IDS?

Comment: Yes, I can do login, throw that exepction sometimes

Comment: @Samuel How are you loading the signing keys in IdentityServer4? Are you using the developer signing credential?

Comment: Thank you @mackie, i solved importing the certificate as you commented!

Comment: hi. i have same problem and i am using the developer signing credential. what i should do for solvind this error? please help me